# cv::Mat frame and SCILAB

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, scilab

I have a frame in opencv wich I don't want to save using  imwrite(), that I use this code to extract each channel and save it and than open the three files and combining a new frame first here is the c++ code :

```
  .........
  mean_fb.open("d:\\mean_blue",ios::out);
ostream osb(&mean_fb);
mean_fg.open("d:\\mean_green",ios::out);
ostream osg(&mean_fg);
mean_fr.open("d:\\mean_red",ios::out);
ostream  osr(&mean_fr);
resultframe *= 1.0/255.0; // adjusting the colors of the mean value 
for(int row = 0; row < resultframe.rows; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < resultframe.cols; col++) {
    //  std::cout << resultframe.at<cv::Vec3f>(row, col)[1] <<std::endl;
        std::cout << resultframe.at<cv::Vec3f>(row, col)[2] <<std::endl;

        //fwrite(&resultframe.at<cv::Vec3f>(row,col )[0],sizeof(float),1,inpR);
        osr<< resultframe.at<cv::Vec3f>(row, col)[0]<<"\n";
        osg<< resultframe.at<cv::Vec3f>(row, col)[1]<<"\n";
        osb<< resultframe.at<cv::Vec3f>(row, col)[2]<<"\n";
    }
}
 .......
```

the saved files are correct so I open them using SCILAB  by the way the frame is 1920*1080  , here is the SCILAB code :

```
  clear 
  clc
  stacksize('max');
  cd 'd:\'
  width = 1080;
  height =1920 ;
  im = zeros(width, height);
     // read the  values of the red channel  

   red  = mgetl('mean_red'); // read the file as  
   red  = matrix(red,[width, height]);
   red  = strtod(red);
   im(:,:,3) = red;//  because opencv defaullt color Model is BGR 
   clear red;  // clear red to get enough stack 



  // read the  values of the green channel  

 green  = mgetl('mean_green'); // read the file as 
 green  = matrix(green,[width,height]);
 green  = strtod(green);
 im(:,:,2) = green;
  clear green;


   // read the  values of the blue channel  

  blue  = mgetl(mean_blue'); // read the file as 
  blue  = matrix(blue,[width, height]);
  blue  = strtod(blue);
  im(:,:,1) =blue ; 
  clear blue;


 imshow(im);/////////////////////////////////////////
```

this a part of the striped image I get [image] :
thanks for your help

Comment: What is your question ? You have described a scenario, have not asked a question. What is your problem ? What answer do you want ?

Comment: the image that get is striped and that's my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you got the width and height parameter reversed. The image might be transposed.

Comment: when switch the width and height I get the right resolution  and just a aprt of the image ?

Comment: Did you also count in the size of the 3 color channels and possibly the alpha channel?

Comment: I didn't, I doesn't make sense why do I get the right  resolution for  a part of the picture by switching the height and the width

Answer (score 0):

After Ted W suggestion I thought that maybe I had to switch the width and height not in SCILAB but in c++ and this worked so here is the code if some one need it :

```
mean_fb.open("d:\\mean_blue",ios::out);
ostream osb(&mean_fb);
mean_fg.open("d:\\mean_green",ios::out);
ostream osg(&mean_fg);
mean_fr.open("d:\\mean_red",ios::out);
ostream  osr(&mean_fr);
  adjusting the colors of the mean value 
for (int col = 0; col < resultframe.cols; col++) {
    for(int row = 0; row < resultframe.rows; row++) {
    //  std::cout << resultframe.at<cv::Vec3f>(row, col)[1] <<std::endl;
        std::cout << resultframe.at<cv::Vec3f>(row, col)[2] <<std::endl;

        //fwrite(&resultframe.at<cv::Vec3f>(row,col )[0],sizeof(float),1,inpR);
        osb<< resultframe.at<cv::Vec3f>(row, col)[0]<<"\n";
        osg<< resultframe.at<cv::Vec3f>(row, col)[1]<<"\n";
        osr<< resultframe.at<cv::Vec3f>(row, col)[2]<<"\n";
    }
}
mean_fb.close();
mean_fr.close();
mean_fg.close();


std_fb.open("d:\\std_blue",ios::out);
ostream std_osb(&std_fb);
std_fg.open("d:\\std_green",ios::out);
ostream std_osg(&std_fg);
std_fr.open("d:\\std_red",ios::out);
ostream  std_osr(&std_fr);

for (int col = 0; col < deviationframe.cols; col++)   {
    for(int row = 0; row < deviationframe.rows; row++) {

        std::cout << deviationframe.at<cv::Vec3f>(row, col)[2] <<std::endl;
        std_osb<< deviationframe.at<cv::Vec3f>(row, col)[0]<<"\n";
        std_osg<< deviationframe.at<cv::Vec3f>(row, col)[1]<<"\n";
        std_osr<< deviationframe.at<cv::Vec3f>(row, col)[2]<<"\n";
    }
}
std_fb.close();
std_fr.close();
std_fg.close();
```